# Material UI v5.11 - Prop sx written twice in responsive

Tags: reactjs, responsive, sx

I received a React program with Material UI v5.11

and appears in it this instruction:

```
<Stack sx={{ flexDirection: { sx: 'column', md: 'row' }}}>
```

and it seems working perfectly.

But I am confused. Why the second sx? `sx: 'column'`

Wouldn't it be right `xs: 'column'` ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ***xs: 'column'*** is the right one.
**By default, Stack arranges items vertically in a column**
The code above is wrong, there is no `sx` as `prop` for `flexDirection`

The code you have above is exactly the same as

```
sx={{ flexDirection: { md: 'row' }}}
```

Since `sx` is not known, it is ignored. and when the size is not `md` (sm or xs) the direction is switched to 'column' so this is why it looks like it is working.

The following lines are equal

```
<Stack sx={{ flexDirection: { sx: 'column', md: 'row' }}}>
<Stack sx={{ flexDirection: { blabla: 'column', md: 'row' }}}>
<Stack sx={{ flexDirection: { md: 'row' }}}>
```